# Onclick remove appended Div - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to **remove** the appended row, when click on "X" button of a specific Div.

**Here is the JsFiddle DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/4/

I am providing CODE here too:

**HTML:**

```
      <p>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_more">Add More</a>
      </p>

<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody class="append_data"></tbody>

<tr>
  <td> 
      <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  </td> 
</tr> 

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#description{
    width:400px;    
}

.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
}

.append_data{
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.add_more').click(function()
                     {
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                         $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+' <a href="javascript:void(0);">X</a></div><br><br>');

                     });
```

Comment: your html is invalid, div as child of tbody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @anton said. Or you can add the remove event to the element itself as per **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/7/)** (but Anton's solution is better)

```
$('.add_more').click(function(){
    var description = $('#description').val();
    $newEl = $('<div class="description_text">'+description+' <a href="javascript:void(0);">X</a></div>');
    $newEl.on("click", function(){$(this).remove();});
    $(".append_data").append($newEl);
});
```

or have the X as the close trigger like this: jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/9

```
    $newEl.on("click", "a", function(){$(this).parent().remove();});
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this, for the dynamically added elements you'll need to use on() and delgate on the closest static element like this :

```
$('.append_data').on('click','.description_text a',function(){
     $(this).closest('.description_text').remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/6/)

You could add to the description_text css

```
margin-bottom:10px;
```

And ignore adding `<br/>` to the append

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/10/)

Comment: This answer is perfect but it is not removing those spaces that DIV covered. It is removing DIV but not the Space of Div

Answer (score 3):

I see nice answers here. Anyway imho the best option is store elements in variables inside function scope. Then you can easy delete every element that was connected with specific cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/8/

JS:

```
$('.add_more').click(function () {
    var description = $('#description').val();
    var deleteButton = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);">X</a>');
    var cell = $('<div class="description_text">' + description + '</div>');
    var spaces = $('<br /><br />');

    cell.append(deleteButton);

    $(".append_data").append(cell);
    spaces.insertAfter(cell);

    deleteButton.click(function () {
        cell.remove();
        spaces.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Very neat. +1 from me.

Comment: In your code, there are extra spaces at the end. So I added them as well ;)